# Regex for 2 different strings accounting for optional elements

Tags: java, regex

I have two strings "2007 AL PLAIN TEXT 5567 (NS)" and "5567" in the second string, I only want to extract one group out of both the strings which is 5567. How do I write a java regex for this ? The format will be 4 digit year, 2 digit jurisdiction, the string plain text, then the number I want to extract and finally (NS) but the problem is all except the number can be optional, How do I write a regex for this that can capture the number 5567 only in a group ?

Comment: Why do you need a regex for the second string if it is already what you are trying to extract?

Comment: See: [regex tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: Because the input can either be one or the other, and not both.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line:

```
String num = input.replaceAll("(.*?)?(\\b\\w{4,}\\b)(\\s*\\(NS\\))?$", "$2");
```

Assuming your target is "a word at least 4 alphanumeric characters long".

Comment: Bohemian, I can only use a regex pattern because it is an external config

Comment: Bohemian, PLAIN TEXT 5567 (NS) .. 5567 could be alphanumeric. Sorry didnt mention that.. it could be 556app9 (NS)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ? quantifier, which means that the match is optional, '?:' groups a match, but doesn't create a backreference for that group.Here is the code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Regexp
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    String x = "2007 AL PLAIN TEXT 5567 (NS)";
    String y = "5567";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "(?:.*[^\\d])?(\\d{4,}){1}(?:.*)?");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);

    while (matcher.find()) 
        {
        System.out.format("Text found in x: => \"%s\"\n",
                  matcher.group(1));
        }

    matcher = pattern.matcher(y);

    while (matcher.find()) 
        {
        System.out.format("Text found in y: => \"%s\"\n",
                  matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ java Regexp
Text found in x: => "5567"
Text found in y: => "5567"
```